# Android Layout: Consistent visible Button Bar

Tags: button, android-layout, onclick, visibility

In my main Activity I have created a bar with buttons on it. Now , I would like the "Button Bar" to always show regardless of what Activity I'm showing. Basically I need the handle the Button events from the "Button Bar" across all Activities. Is this possible, and what best practice to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use includes inside a Merge. The includes can be re used inside any view.

```
 <com.testmerge.TitleBar
    id="@+id/titlebar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="35dip" 
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:paddingTop="0dip"
    android:background="@drawable/title_bar"
 />


<com.testmerge.OkCancelBar
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="60dip" 
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:paddingTop="0dip"
    android:background="@drawable/header_bkgrnd"
/>

<!--"#AA000000"-->
```